# Fire next event up, but not after that

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

For a page, I've been given a link wrapped inside a label, like this:

```
<label for='checkbox_elem'>
    Links to <a href='somepage.php' target='anotherwindow'>another page.</a>
</label>
```

When the user clicks on the link in all browser, the page is spawned in a new tab as envisioned, but in Firefox the checkbox linked to the label is also selected. This is a non-desired behavior.

I want to run some jQuery to allow the link to pop, but to kill the event thereafter. I have the following, which works, but isn't very elegant:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('label a').click(function(e){
        open($(this).attr('href'), $(this).attr('target'));
        return false;
    });
});
```

Can any of you think of a more elegant way to do this than to replicate the element's behavior manually and kill the event?

---

As an aside, I've been trying with `stopPropagation`, but haven't had much success.

Also, please note that the above solution *does work*, but I am looking for something *more elegant* for generically stopping events from propagating past their first call. (The first native call. If I add a callback, I still want the native element behavior to fire, but not that of its parent) .

Comment: That is elegant enough.  Move on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try stopping the event from propagating at the label.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('label').click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Comment: Tried this one. The label needs to retain its normal click behavior, except when the event is coming from an <a> element. This disables the label behavior.

Comment: I'd say FireFox is not doing what it's supposed to. I tried stopping propagation on every combination of mouse events and elements I could think of and nothing seems to prevent firefox from toggling the checkbox. I did notice however that the change event reports it's ultimate event source is a click event on the text node within the link. Not sure how to catch that event though...

Answer (score 0):

You could use $(elem).one(fn) -- http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: I want my handler to continue to be called on every click, but I need it to override the bubble-up *after* the normal <a> element event is fired. It looks like one() will not change my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should change your html to:

```
<label for='checkbox_elem'>Links to </label>
<a href='somepage.php' target='anotherwindow'>another page.</a>
```

and use no javascript at all?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Not my HTML, it's coming out of a CMS controlled by non-technical users. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you are allowed to change the html on client-side, you can always move the links outside the label like this,

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('label').find('a').each(function(){
        var $anchor = $(this);        
        $(this).closest('label').after($anchor);
    });
});​
```

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eNeep/)

Comment: I actually like this approach (there are a few more complications, but generally workable), but I'm not sure it's *more* elegant to rewrite HTML to get around such issues.

Comment: honestly, I can't think of any other approach... Cause as you said, you have no control on the source of the html...

Answer (score 0):

This one:

```
<label> test <a href="#">Test</a> <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" /></label>
```

Or even:

```
<label for="test1"> test <a href="#">Test</a> <input type="checkbox" name="test1" id="test1" class="checkbox" /></label>
```

And js:

```
$('a').click(function(e){
    var t=$(this);
    window.open(t.attr('href'), t.attr('target'));
    return false;
});
```

Works for me. Maybe there is smth that interfere with your script?

Comment: I can use window.open, but that is a pretty specific override, and pretty kludgy. The purpose of my question is to see if there is an elegant solution to the problem, rather than the hack I already have.

Comment: Oups, i didn't get the part with 'a more elegant way' :D However, you cant' Maybe if you play with `position:absolute` with the link, but I consider that is more ugly than this.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.one()` instead of `.click()`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('label a').one(function(e){
        open($(this).attr('href'), $(this).attr('target'));
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: This is identical to the code that I posted, but only prevents the label click on the first time that the user does it. The one() function is unfortunately not suitable for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

KISS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('label a').click(function(e){
        open($(this).attr('href'), $(this).attr('target'));
        $(this).parent().click(); //Click the label again to reverse the effects of the first click.
        return false;
    });
});
```